# gdal2tiles.py multithreaded only works with base tileset

Tags: gdal, gdal2tiles

I'm using GDAL 2.4.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 Installed from the ubuntugis-unstable repository.

When I use the gdal2tiles.py with the '--processes=n' flag the multithreaded operation works fine for processing the base tileset. Then, generating the overview tiles is only single threaded. Is this the expected behavior, or is something amiss in my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the ticket https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4379 and the pull request https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/201 the --processes flag affects only base tiles.